# mysql table not creating by wordpress plugin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am using this code to create a table but it is not working . I have tried a single line SQL query but is not working also (Not sure it is a nonsense try). Is there anyone to help me immediately to resolve this issue?

```
function rswl_activaiton(){
    global $wpdb;
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'rswl_entries';
    $charset = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    if( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE ".$table_name ) != $table_name ){
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name ( 
            rswl_entry_id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            rswl_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            rswl_model VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            rswl_date VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            rswl_ebay_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            rswl_email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            rswl_status VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
            PRIMARY KEY (rswl_entry_id)
        ) $charset;";
        dbDelta( $sql );
    };
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'rswl_activaiton' );
```

Comment: Show exactly `$sql` variable value. And complete error message.

Comment: @akina I don't understand

Comment: What is unclear? Show exactly value stored in `$sql` variable immediately before `dbDelta( $sql );` statement.

Comment: @akina Would you please write the code?

Comment: `var_dump(@sql);`

Comment: @akina not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue myself. I was missing a comma (,) after `rswl_status VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL`

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name ( 
            rswl_entry_id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            rswl_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            rswl_model VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            rswl_date VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            rswl_ebay_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            rswl_email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            rswl_status VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (rswl_entry_id)
        ) $charset;";
```